# cannot access /dev/mem using sudo

Tags: c

I'm trying to access /dev/mem, using the following c code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    int fd, tam=4096;
    uint32_t volatile *dir;
    fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY); //file descriptor to physical memory

    if(fd == -1) {
        perror("Cannot open memory file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    dir = mmap(NULL, tam, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0xfee00000);

    close(fd);
}
```

I've tried to run the program using sudo, but it won't allow me to access the /dev/mem file. I also activated the setuid bit, using the following command:

> sudo chmod u+s filename

None of these approaches seem to work.

The output of:

> $ ls -l /dev

is:

```
crw-r-----  1 root  kmem      1,     1 dic 10 15:44 mem
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: Maybe this bites you: http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0801.3/3426.html

Comment: For me, the sample program, run as root, works.  ("chmod u+s filename" isn't enoough.  Also do "chown root filename" first.)  Except the mapping also gets an error : EPERM.  It may be (reasonably) that you can't mmap a character device.  It may be subject to a file seal.

Comment: It turns out the mmap failure was the offset.  Changing 0xfee00000 to 0 made it work.